# Keybinding Wacom tablet control panel in windows

Tags: autohotkey, wacom

I'm looking for any help regarding changing a wacom tablet control panel option in Win 7.
 **What i need to do;**
I own a Wacom Tablet and I wish to change one of its options, "Tip Feel". 
This option controls how the pen works, set to "soft" it makes the pen require less pressure and acts like a felt tip or soft brush. Set to "firm" it makes the pen require lots of pressure and feels like a very hard pencil or technical pen.

*Ultimately I would bind 3 keys to three different "tip feels" - soft, medium and firm*

Below is the control panel interface and the option I'm interested in is highlighted in red

http://www.fuzzypiglet.com/crap/cp.jpg

**Technically this would mean;**
1. Opening the control panel
2. Selecting several options at the top (Tablet - Intuos4 L), (Tool - Grip pen), (Application - Painter 12 x64)
3. Changing the tip feel slider to "soft" (7 step option so maybe as a number "1")
4. Closing the control panel and restoring the Painter application

Is this software right for what I want to do? Ive no experience with programming at all apart from a bit of html.

Comment: Yes, autohotkey will be able to do what you want.

Comment: Do you have to go through all the menu's or are there keyboard shortcuts you could use to control these settings? And Yes! AutoHotKey would be able to do this (in almost all cases).

Comment: its not a menu item or in the painter ap[plication, its a windows control panel. I have looked at the software and it doesnt seem much help at all.

Comment: There is a config file located somewhere in the Users folder. I think for Intuos4 it's called Wacom_Tablet.dat. It should be either plaintext (one setting per line) or XML. Filename and format differs between driver versions, though. Locate that and there's an entry for the pressure response. I don't have the reference handy, but basically you can control the response curve completely by modifying that file, then restarting the tablet service. So perhaps that's an option?